# how can I center this text and remove it's default height

Tags: css

I just started to learn html and css again and I am struggling with some weird stuff that I didn't see before.
[image]

I have this button

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Explore</a>
```

this all good but if you pay attention there is some margin or just some space at the bottom

[image]
inside the blue square I just want to be the text height so it will be centered perfectly

Comment: If I got you correctly you want to remove bottom space highlighted in blue, you can use   line-height: 0px;  in your style

Comment: that's not a strange space, that space is reserver for descender `qpjy`

Comment: I just don't get it, line-height doesn't change it and I think it's because of the underline, it is still there but not visible? https://codepen.io/madalinbogdea/pen/MWpROLX not so much code

Answer (score 0):

I check your codes in my editor and it is correct perfectly. Your codes' problem is due to over-code or other ones.

This image is from my Chrome browser:
[image]

Comment: yes that's the problem I think but I removed all the css styling and there still the empty space, I made a pen isn't so much code https://codepen.io/madalinbogdea/pen/MWpROLX

Comment: I used text-decoration: none as a default reset for all <a> tags and if I remove it then it seems like it's because of the underline

Comment: @MadalinBogdea have you read the comment of Temani Afif underneath your question?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, I tried this too but nothing. anyway I had to let it like that

Comment: @MadalinBogdea not the one of Muhammad, the one of Temani - lol